# Automatically synchronize a SharePoint site to all computers in a domain

Tags: office-365, deployment, domain

Is it in any way possible to setup a SharePoint site to synchronize to a local folder automatically for all computers in a domain (for example via GPO/registry settings/...)?

I am asking so that each of our employees does not have to manually click the Groove client icon and select "Synchronize new library", as depicted in the screenshot below.

[image]

We are using SharePoint Online from Office 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have mapped our department sites like a network drive to the users computers. Steps as follows

- Click on Start > search for services.msc and right click on Webclient service, go to its properties and change it to Automatic from manual and restart the same
- Open Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet Options > Trusted sites under Security tab > Add https://*.sharepoint.com and https://*.microsoftonline.com to trusted sites
- Restart Internet explorer > Sign in to Office 365 portal with "Keep me signed in" checked > Open the library > Click on Library from the Ribbon > Open with Explorer > Copy the address
- Open My Computer > Right click on Computer > Map network drive > Paste the address > Finish

The address path can be a library path or a site path to map all libraries.

Here are some more instruction in article
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2616712

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible but another workaround you can try if you want to sync single document library with all employees.

- Use the New team sites and install the one drive for business client. then sync the same document library.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-Office-365-file-storage-and-sharing-7aa9cdc8-2245-4218-81ee-86fa7c35f1de

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-your-Office-365-team-site-for-file-storage-and-sharing-70a62f09-45ea-4968-8482-43cddfb8cc01